# How Would Owls React in the 0 Gravity of a Space Station

Tags: biology, space

The setting is the typical Earth is going to be destroyed by a rain of Asteroids/Bolides and so The ISS is repurposed be accommodate a lot of humans almost reaching 300 or so working together to maintain the ship, the frozen seed/sperm/embryos, the a database of digitally stored DNA of almost all of the species. I realized that stuffing so many people to work year on end for a possibly fruitless cause will take its toll on them. So I want to send a Professor someone social someone who knows all most all of the people of the Space Station and I want to sent his pet owl too.
So I want to how will it react to 0 Gravity? how will it effect its balancing organs, how will it mess with its sense of night and day, will it be detrimental to its health???

Comment: So, the question boils down to [how do birds cope with zero gravity](https://gizmodo.com/ejector-seats-weightless-kittens-and-heat-chamber-tes-1586971531). Night and day can after all be regulated by shutters and lights.

Comment: This sounds both like a story set in a world, and, specifically, Seveneves, which you namedropped in another question.

Comment: Ehm, Surprised!

Comment: @jdunlop yup you got its highly inspired by Seveneves or more of like a parallel universe of sevenves

Comment: @EveninginGethsemane that's pretty much a complete answer right there. You should post that.

Comment: Please go ahead @StarfishPrime, I'm away from now for a while.

Comment: They wouldn't give a hoot.

Comment: When there's air and prey, I think the owls love zero gravity. Mice floating around everywhere..

Comment: Not a good idea. The owls would upset the goats.

Answer (score 4):

Turns out that people have, in fact, subjected various colors and flavors of animal to brief moments of microgravity, presumably in the name of science.

Evening in Gethsemane linked this gizmodo article: [Here's What Happens When A Pigeon Tries To Fly In Zero Gravity](https://gizmodo.com/ejector-seats-weightless-kittens-and-heat-chamber-tes-1586971531) which includes a video, but here's a small blurry gif if you are too impatient to visit the source:

[image: Pigeons in spaaaaaace]

The bird are clearly confused an unhappy and do things like somersault and fly in arbitrary orientations, but they do in fact seem able to fly. With a suitably young and robust bird, it doesn't seem implausible that they'd be able to adapt to life in microgravity.

That just leaves you with the problem of a panicky distressed bird of prey equipped with various razor-sharp flesh-ripping appendages, shedding poop and feathers and probably impossible to feed its correct diet.

I suspect the owl's time on the station will be short and unhappy for all concerned.

Comment: The astronauts don't wear space helmets, so these birds fly, because there is air inside this zero-G flight cabin. Only issue is, their balance does not work. The usual up- and down perception is unavailable, hence the confusion. Difficult to say these birds are unhappy..

Comment: Difficult to say indeed, but I get that interpretation: flying into walls because of a lack of control over the direction in which you fly doesn't sound particularly appealing.

Answer (score 3):

The bird eventually dies of dehydration or starvation unless medically cared for.

All the answers look at the immediate effects of birds trying to fly and maneuver, and that's interesting but pointless, because of one rather important fact: avians require gravity in order to [eat](https://www.rspb.org.uk/birds-and-wildlife/natures-home-magazine/birds-and-wildlife-articles/how-do-birds-survive/food-glorious-food/) and [drink](https://www.birdwatchersdigest.com/bwdsite/solve/faqs/how-do-birds-drink-water.php).

Birds, unlike most mammals, are unable to create suction to pull water and food up against gravity. It is possible (not recommended, but possible), for a human to eat and drink lying down or with their heads below the level of the torso, sometimes even totally inverted. See a giraffe drinking as an example. Birds need to raise their heads up to allow gravity to pull the food/water into the throat, where muscular contractions can then take over to move the food along.

So humans don't need to worry about it because gravity isn't a necessity in eating or drinking, so we don't have a problem in zero G. An avian would require someone to force the food and water down its throat until it was deep enough that the muscles could take over to propel it along.